# JavaScript library for extracting relevant CSS

Tags: javascript, css, npm, jquery-plugins

Is there a JavaScript library that can extract the style from HTML?

For example; given the following html it will output a style element that contains all the **computed styling applied to each of those elements**?

Input...

```
<div class="container no-wrap">

    <p>foo</p>

    <footer class="thumbnail">
        <span>bar</span>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Output...

```
// The library/utility has inspected all elements and discovered all styling applied 
// to the elements and the classes
<style type="text/css">

    div {
        margin: 0;
        background-color: red;
    }

    p {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family: arial;
    }

    span {
        color: #fff;
    }

    footer {

    }

    .container {
        ...
    }

    .no-wrap {
        ....
    }

    .thumbnail {
        ...
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

A library is not necessary. You can iterate `document.styleSheets` and `.rules` property of each `CSSStyleSheet` to get `.selectorText` and `.cssText` properties

```js
for (let sheet of document.styleSheets) {
  for (let rules of sheet.rules) {
    let {selectorText, cssText} = rules;
    console.log(selectorText, cssText)
  }
}
```

```html
<style>
  div {
    color:blue;
  }
</style>
<div>abc</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the computed property of each element in `document`, and each property and value set at the element you can use `Object.entries()` and `window.getComputedProperty()`

```js
for (let element of document.querySelectorAll("*")) {
  for (let [key, prop] of Object.entries(window.getComputedStyle(element))) {
    console.log(element.tagName, element.id, element.className, key, prop)
  }
}
```

```html
<style>
  div {
    color: blue;
  }
</style>
```